# "on_session" vs "off_session" in Stripe

Tags: python, stripe-payments, payment, checkout, python-stripe-api

I can set `on_session` and `off_session` for [payment_intent_data.setup_future_usage](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-setup_future_usage) and [payment_method_options.card.setup_future_usage](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_method_options-card-setup_future_usage) as shown below. *I use **Python**:

```py
checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
    # ...
    payment_intent_data={
        "setup_future_usage": "on_session" # Here
    },
    payment_method_options={
        "card": {
            "setup_future_usage": "on_session" # Here
        },
    },
    # ...
)
```

```py
checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
    # ...
    payment_intent_data={
        "setup_future_usage": "off_session" # Here
    },
    payment_method_options={
        "card": {
            "setup_future_usage": "off_session" # Here
        }
    },
    # ...
)
```

But, I cannot exactly understand what are `on_session` and `off_session` even though I read [Optimizing cards for future payments](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents#future-usage) on Stripe Doc.

So, what are `on_session` and `off_session`?

Answer (score 2):

Off-session payments refers to payments where the customer isn’t present (on your website or application) at the time of payment.

For example, when you sign up for a Subscription on the merchant's website and provide your card details for the first payment - you're `on-session`.

Subsequent payments where your card is auto-debited - you're `off-session`.

Answer (score 0):

**on_session payment:** Imagine you're at a store, you choose some items, and you pay for them at the cashier while you're still in the store. You're actively involved in the payment process.

**off_session payment:** Now, think of a situation where you set up an automatic payment for your monthly bills. You don't make the payment every month; it happens automatically even if you're not actively doing anything at that moment. This is like an off_session payment because you're not "in the store" when the payment occurs.

In essence, on_session payments need your active involvement (like making an online purchase), while off_session payments are automatic and can occur without your direct interaction (like paying your monthly subscription or bills).

Answer (score -4):

"On_session" and "off_session" refer to the usage of a saved payment method for future transactions. "On_session" means the payment method is stored for future use after the current transaction is complete. "Off_session" means the payment method is not stored for future use and can only be used for the current transaction.